# Yii createCommand($sql)->queryAll() with index

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am trying to get the PerkID as the resultant array index but it is still returning the array with indicies 0,1,2 and the PerkID is in the next layer.

```
$sql='SELECT PerkID,Amount FROM perks';
$perks=$connection->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(array("index"=>"PerkID"));
```

result is

> array(34) { [0]=> array(2) { ["PerkID"]=> string(7) "2285513" ["Amount"]=> string(1) "5" }...

Comment: Check @Carlos Belisario answer i think this will work

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of the [queryAll](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryAll-detail) method, but i don't understand what is the problem, you can iterate of all rows of the array with a foreach,

```
foreach ($perks as $perk) {
    echo $perk['PerkID'];
}
```

Off-topic why not use the active record of Yii?

Answer (score 0):

try using [CHtml::listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail)

So you can get you result by this

```
$sql='SELECT PerkID,Amount FROM perks';
$perks=$connection->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

$result = CHtml::listData($perks,'PerkID','Amount');
```